# Windows 10 UEFI Bootloader ignores Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, windows-10

I've been working to install Ubuntu 16.04 on my Acer Aspire R 14 laptop which came pre-installed with Windows 10 and a UEFI Firmware system.

I've looked through nearly every thread and none of them seem to have any effect.

I've partitioned my hard drive and have now installed (and uninstalled) Ubuntu about a dozen times varying the mode in which I installed it (Secure Boot enabled vs. Disabled) and where I attempted to install the Grub Bootloader when given the option to do "something else" when installing ubuntu (/dev/sda, /dev/sda1 (efi partition), /dev/sda6 (linux partition)).

I've attempted to mount and install grub via:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sda6 /mnt
$ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi  # and /mnt/boot
$ for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
$ sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/ # for network compatibility
$ modprobe efivars
$ sudo chroot /mnt
# apt-get install --reinstall grub-efi-amd64
```

I've also tried using the automated boot-repair tool.

These runs completed successfully with the given output:
http://paste2.org/9Hzds0J5
http://paste2.org/KJt55GbI

I even followed up afterward in entering the given windows command:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi

My issue is that no matter what I do, the ubuntu boot partition is not recognized by windows or the Firmware.  For example, my boot order is:

1. HDD: WDC WD10SPCX-21KHST0
2. Windows Boot Manager
3. USB HDD: KinstonDataTraveler 3.0  (My Ubuntu USB stick)
4. USB FDD:
5. Network Boot-IPV4:
6. USB CDROM:
7. Network Boot-IPV6:

My boot system is the InsydeH2O Setup Utility.

My disk partitions are:

- /dev/sda1 EFI System
- /dev/sda2 Microsoft Reserved
- /dev/sda3 Microsoft Basic Data
- /dev/sda4 Windows Recovery
- /dev/sda5 Linux Swap
- /dev/sda6 Linux Filesystem

Ideally I'd like to get my computer booting to grub since I've never had issues booting windows from grub before.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. Thanks to all the members of the askubuntu forums for the answers they've posted to similar questions that have gotten me this far.  I've read most of them, but was not allowed to cite them due to the limited number of urls that I could post.

Answer (score 2):

Two things.  Make sure you are in UEFI mode in your Live Session.  You can test this by running this from the terminal:

```
$ dmesg | egrep "EFI v"
```

The output will be blank if you are in Legacy.

Also, be sure to include `update-grub` in your grub repair steps.  The steps below should resolve your issue.  The bold characters in the steps are unique for you based on the info in your question.

```
 1:$ sudo mount /dev/sda6 /mnt
 2:$ for i in /sys /proc /run /dev; do sudo mount --bind "$i" "/mnt/$i"; done
 3:$ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi
 5:$ sudo chroot /mnt
 6:# grub-install /dev/sda
 7:# update-grub
 8:# exit
 9:$ for i in /sys /proc /run /dev; do sudo umount "/mnt/$i"; done
10:$ sudo umount /mnt/boot/efi
11:$ exit
```

Comment: This is indeed nonsense, the drive `sdb` is a 7.2 GB flash-drive with only one partition `sdb1` and contains the Ubuntu-installer. Look at the boot-info-summary!

Comment: @mook765 Please stop staking me.  That's inappropriate behavior for this site.  The information I provided to the user is based on where he specified in his message.  When he test the steps and give a response, he'll have the same success that 10's of other using the same steps has achieved.  There's no need for you to downvote all my messages.

Comment: @mook765 I won't downvote your message, but I wouldn't advise the requisite you specify of a need to boot into Windows to fix the problem.  The problem can be resolve by the Ubunutu installation disk and the computer's BIOS.  Windows can actually be left alone.  Please notice my message states that the `/dev/sda6` is variable that is to be changed depending on the installed OS.

Comment: I apologize for the word "nonsense", it was  inappropriate. But your commands contained faulty information, that is just reality. Nothing personal, I see you edited this mistake and will undo my down-vote, let the OP decide himself. Grub-EFI has already been reinstalled as we can see in the boot-info-summary...

Answer (score 0):

You installed Ubuntu in legacy-mode on the drive `sda` where Windows8 is installed in UEFI-mode. Boot-repair reinstalled Grub for UEFI-mode.
Some machines need more workaround, it depends on the UEFI-firmware of your computer. The first thing to try is to follow this advice from your
boot-info-summary:

```
If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order
in your BIOS.If your BIOS does not allow to change the boot order, change
the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader. For example you can boot
into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
```