# Boot menu is not showing option for Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, grub-efi

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 together with Windows 10 using dual boot. At the installation part there was no **install alongside Windows** option, so I did it using **Something else** with some difficulties. [Here is my installation path.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/870930/hesitant-as-to-whether-to-preceed-with-dual-boot-installation)
I used Windows for some time and wanted to use Ubuntu and tried to boot it through boot menu. But there was no option for Ubuntu, it only shows 
this window[image]

Question: How can boot back to Ubuntu?
By the way, I tried Boot Repair Disk (software) to reinstall Grub menu, it failed to go on due to Internet connection.

Thank you all!

Comment: Do you have RAID?

Comment: Could you please run [Boot-Info](//help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info) and [edit] your question to include a link to its resulting info log? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The Ubuntu installation will detect the UEFI mode and install a Grub option that you'll be able to find in your computer's BIO.  Your image shows that you have the Windows Boot Manager set for booting.  Use the option of your BIOS settings to change from `Windows Boot Manager` to `Ubuntu`.  The Windows Boot Manager doesn't show Ubuntu in the menu.  But when you select the `Grub Boot Manager` (identified by `Ubuntu`), it'll take you to a menu to either boot **Ubuntu** or **Windows**.

**This is a method to identify your details of your partitions:**

Type in the command, indicated by the `$` prompt.  You'll get an output similar to the example below.

```
$ sudo parted -l
```

```
Model: ATA ST500LM012 HN-M5 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB   537MB   fat32           EFI System Partition          boot, esp
 2      538MB   53.0GB  52.4GB  ext4
 3      53.0GB  157GB   104GB   ntfs            WINDOWS                       msftdata
 4      157GB   158GB   472MB   ntfs                                          hidden, diag
 5      158GB   158GB   16.8MB                  Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 6      492GB   500GB   8008MB  linux-swap(v1)
```

The output explained:

- The second line specifies the drive as `/dev/sda`.
- The numbers column is showing the partition number.  Partition #1 as indicated above is `/dev/sda1`.  It's also indicating it's the '/boot/efi` partition by it's **Name** and **flags** columns.
- The number `2` (a 52GB partition) is an `ext4` partition.  This, in this case, is where `Ubuntu` is install.  It's partition `/dev/sda2`.

Those are the partitions you are concerned with.  When running the steps provided in the [this link](https://askubuntu.com/a/833721/29012), they are what would be replaced for the **bold** print.

### Run These Commands

```
 1:  $ sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
 2:  $ for i in /sys /proc /run /dev; do sudo mount --bind "$i" "/mnt/$i"; done
 3:  $ sudo mount /dev/sda6 /mnt/boot/efi
 5:  $ sudo chroot /mnt
 6:  # grub-install /dev/sda
 7:  # update-grub
 8:  # exit
 9:  $ for i in /sys /proc /run /dev; do sudo umount "/mnt/$i"; done
10:  $ sudo umount /mnt/boot/efi
11:  $ exit
```

Comment: I don't have Grub Boot Manager option in my BIOS system...
When Boot mode select is "UEFI with CSM" or "UEFI"  I have 5 boot options in  fixed boot order priorities:
Hard Disk: Windows Boot Manager (Intel RAIDOIMSVolume)

USB CD/DVD

USB Hard Disk

CD/DVD

Network
And when Boot mode select is LEGACY, I have following 5 options:

Hard Disk

USB CD/DVD

USB Hard Disk

CD/DVD
Network.

Comment: Your message indicates you installed Ubuntu, then proceeded to use Windows.  It's a common occurrence on this site for users to loose their Grub during Windows 10's updates.  If you are not seeing Grub in the BIOs, this might be an occasion.  Reinstall Grub, which will detect your Windows and Ubuntu.  You can perform the steps in [this link](http://askubuntu.com/a/833721/29012) to **reinstall Grub**.  Replace the Bold **/dev/sda6** in the answer withe the partition of your Ubuntu.  Replace the **/dev/sda1** with your `/boot/efi` boot partition.

Comment: I am a newbie here in Ubuntu, how do I know the partition of my Ubuntu?

Comment: Give me a few minutes to format and output and add it to my answer.

Comment: I updated my answer with a formatted description.  I'll take some time later to format it better if you still have problems following it.

Comment: SIr, I selected Legacy mode and prioritized  Hard Disk and rebooted my laptop and it automatically booted to Ubuntu...

Comment: There was no place to place sudo parted -l.
 I got confused.  Here is my results:
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Number  Start   End    Size    File system     Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  528GB  528GB   ntfs            Basic data partition  msftdata
 2      528GB   958GB  429GB   ntfs            Basic data partition  msftdata
 3      958GB   960GB  2048MB  linux-swap(v1)
 4      960GB   970GB  10.2GB  ext4
 5      970GB   991GB  20.5GB  ext4
 6      991GB   991GB  5243kB                                        bios_grub

Comment: I can't make out what you have posted in the comment.  Please add that output to your question so that I can understand it better.  It might contain the information for me to give you the exact commands to fix your grub.

Comment: there is  a result after typing `sudo parted -l`:

`Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB

 1      1049kB  528GB  528GB   ntfs            Basic data partition  msftdata,
 2      528GB   958GB  429GB   ntfs            Basic data partition  msftdata,
 3      958GB   960GB  2048MB  linux-swap(v1),
 4      960GB   970GB  10.2GB  ext4,
 5      970GB   991GB  20.5GB  ext4,
 6      991GB   991GB  5243kB                                        bios_grub`

I can't post it as it is, sorry!

Comment: @Sohib Please look at your question.  Click on **Edit** on your question.  Then post this output to your question.  I will then edit my answer and post the exact lines that you will have to type in to resolve your issue.  This is similar to what David Foerster has commented in your question.  He wants to see this and more.  The information needs to be in your question, not in a comment.

Comment: I edited my question.  Look at the bottom that says **Run these commands**.  Based on what I can make out from your comment, those are the exact commands that you should type in to fix your issue.  Run each of the 11 commands.  If one of them gives an error, please post the error you get.  If you don't get any errors, you will have a new selectable **Boot** entry in your bios called **Ubuntu**.  Select that one and you'll have the option of booting to either `Windows` or `Ubuntu`.

Comment: I think it is not working. When I typed `sudo mount /dev/sda6 /mnt/boot/efi` it is showing `mount: mount point /mnt/boot/efi doesn't exist`
 Are you taking into consideration that I am not able to write these code blocks to normal terminal because of flickering of the terminal. I am writing these things after forcing the terminal to show up every time by pressing ctrl+alt+f1.

Comment: @Sohib My consideration is what you typed above on **Jan 15 at 5:36**.   Did you boot to the Live USB drive?  Was your terminal flickering when you typed that message?  I'm trying to get upto date with what has changed and what you are doing different since you were given the steps.

Comment: That time I didn't use Live USB as I remember. I just selected Legacy mode and prioritized Hard Disk and rebooted my laptop and it automatically booted to Ubuntu. Then I thought the problem was gone and did other installations like Cuda  and CuDNN etc... As time goes by, it is becoming difficult to remember what I did.
Please see the question I recently posted, I have given more information [there](http://askubuntu.com/questions/874017/need-a-solution-to-a-blinking-screen)

Comment: That the confusion.  The steps will not work from a mounted partition with the OS.  It was assumed that you were booting to a Live USB to repair the problem.  You had linked the steps provided for Boot-info which describes using the Live USB or DVD.  To fix your problem and be able to have a choice to see both Windows and Ubuntu in the Boot menu you would have to fix this via a Live USB or DVD.  Will you boot to a live USB and run this command and append the output to your Question:  `sudo lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,fstype;sudo parted -l`

Comment: Sir, I wrote Ubuntu to my USB Flash via Ultra ISO and booted it, now it is showing `gfxboot.c32: not a COM32R image`.
Sorry if I might not understand...

Comment: It's no problem.  As long as you respond and try I don't mind using other words to explain the steps.  Are you saying you no longer have the USB or DVD that you used to install Ubuntu?  If you have lost the disk that you I can take the time to explain to you how to successfully make one and boot to it.  Being able to boot to a USB or DVD is an important part of fixing many problems with Ubuntu (or Windows for that matter).

Comment: I downloaded Ubuntu from [ubuntu.com](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and have burnt Ubuntu with Ultra ISO into my 16GB USB Flash on Windows 10 system. I changed the **boot menu mode** to **Legacy** and prioritized the USB Hard Disk to get access to USB Flash when I switch my computer on. Then after shutting down the computer I plugged the USB Flash in my computer's USB port . All I am saying is that when I switch on my computer,  it prints: `gfxboot.c32: not a COM32R image` repeatedly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52179/discussion-between-l-d-james-and-sohib).