# unable to switch to Ubuntu after installing Ubuntu Gnome

Tags: uninstall, system-settings

Recently I've had login loop problem, even after trying several solutions given in the forums. I ended up installing Gnome  as suggested [here as Solution 3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590561/ubuntu-14-04-login-loop-problem).

After rebooting, the desktop changed to Ubuntu Gnome, but still
didn't solve the loop problem. then I went to BIOS and changed the boot priority to another option, didn't work, then again came back to previous priority and now I can't even access to that login screen. When I switch the computer on I have purple screen suggesting ***Ubuntu**, **Advanced options for Ubuntu**, and **System setup**. Once I hit *Ubuntu it goes through some process[image: shown here] 
Then the screen gets  dark for about 4 seconds and quickly shows up [image: this] for a very very short time (can't even see with natural eyes)[3]]
And this repeats infinitely.

I think I corrupted the Ubuntu system by trying too many things.

How can I solve this case? 
If there is no way,How can I uninstall Ubuntu from my computer without damaging Windows system?

Thank you for your time and advice!

Comment: when I type something, I can see them written after login: as in the second image, but I can write only when it is shown. If  I use Ctrl + alt + f1, I can type for a short time, then it gets dark again.
when I hit the power off, it shows Starting WPA supplicant, OK (in green), Started WPA supplicant. then it is switched off with strange noise- like a rupture.

Comment: [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/871684/29012) to your original boot problem would have resolved it.  The steps will most likely still resolve the problem even after your recent experiments.

Comment: @L. D. James. Those 11 commands should be written to the terminal which is accessed through **Ctrl+Alt+F1**, right? Although it blinks and writing something is only possible when it is shown?

Comment: I'm sure, as I mentioned the linked answer would resolve your issue.  If you have problems or questions about it, it would be better for the community to place the comments where the answer is.  This way if the answer, for some reason, doesn't work it could be fixed there.  Others with similar issues will find it easier to follow the resolution by following the comment.  Others that are contributing to the fix would find it be able to easier add their input.  Nice your taking the time to look at it.  If for some reason it doesn't work (which I consider very unlikely) I would like to know.

Comment: I think it is not working. When I typed `sudo mount /dev/sda6 /mnt/boot/efi` it is showing **mount: mount point /mnt/boot/efi doesn't exist** 

Are you taking into consideration that I am not able to write these code blocks to normal terminal because of flickering of the terminal. I am writing these things after forcing the terminal to show up every time by pressing ctrl+alt+f1.

Comment: The information you are typing here should be typed to the answer so that it can be fixed.  You should do this same followup on all the questions that you type.  Some you are provided solutions, give followups to the answers and comments that are provided and you'll find that it'll help you to understand your system better and soon loose your **novice/new to Ubuntu**  state.  Understanding and following up on one issue will make it easier for the next issue.  This will help you regardless of which OS you decide to use.

Comment: I posted a new question with detailed information, please follow this [link] (http://askubuntu.com/questions/874017/need-a-solution-to-a-blinking-screen)